# Laravel join error while joining using model

Tags: laravel

I am trying to write a join between two tables. I have both tables as models and I am trying to join them. Here is what I have tried,

```
Route::get('test', function () {
    //order details
    $orders_details = OrderDetails::
    where('SKU','LIKE','ROUTEINS%')
    ->limit(10)
    ->join('[dbo].[Orders]', '[dbo].[Orders].OrderNumber', '=', '31966862'
    ->get();
    return response()->json($orders);
});
```

Error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')'
```

Comment: You forgot the closing `)` after `'31966862'`: (`->join('[dbo].[Orders]', '[dbo].[Orders].OrderNumber', '=', '31966862')`... Something unclear about that syntax error message?

Comment: Hey @fuddin, Check your code having no closing bracket so far, that's the reason for that error occur.